# Wireless Audio On A Budget

Tags: wireless, budget, low-budget, transmitter

I am in need of an in-ear monitor system for my Church's band.

We currently use a [Yamaha - LS9-32](http://www.yamahaproaudio.com/global/en/products/mixers/ls9/specifications.jsp) mixer, and are on a budget. Now, I am not a complete audio quality freak, but I do appreciate it. I was thinking about rigging [one of these things](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5-8G-FPV-200mW-AV-Wireless-Transmitter-TX-Rx-Receiver-TS351-RC805-Kit-2KM-HL7H-/121813861559?hash=item1c5cac04b7:g:aZUAAOSwqu9U0zuc)
to transmit audio across about 100 ft.

I was wondering if anyone had tried this before, and/or knew of any downsides? Thanks!

Comment: Please use this syntax [link's name](URL) to make your post more readable. Best :)

Comment: The product you are linking to is not an audio wireless system but an audio+video wireless system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My limited experience is that going cheap in this area can be disappointing. Colored tone, dropouts , etc is not worth it. Am now saving for a line6 system.

Comment: I couldn't find any in ear wireless system on line6 website. Can you point to one ?